# How to config Laravel Router some route rule work on different path?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I deployed my Laravel 5 project on `A.com`, I also want put it under `B.com/a`. For some reason, the `/a` path I should handle it in router.

So in router I write:

`Route::get('post','PostController@index');
Route::get('a/post','PostController@index');`

It's not a good way because there is redundancy， especially there are a lot of other route rules.

In the doc, there is only `{xx}?` to handle optional param, but in my project, it's not param instead of a static string.

It's there any better way to combine two lines?

Comment: If there is more router, which starts with the same prefix, you can use route prefix. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-prefixes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a route prefix within a foreach loop. That'd allow you to quickly and easily manage the prefixes on your routes while keeping them all in one place.

```
foreach([null, 'a'] as $prefix) {
    Route::group(['prefix' => $prefix], function () {
        // Your routes here
    });
}
```

The routes not prefixed will take precedence as their routes would be generated first in this case. You could just as easily swap the array around if necessary.

If you really wanted to do it in a single route definition you could do it using a regular expression to match the route.

```
Route::get('{route}', function () {
    dd('Browsing ' . app('request')->path());

})->where('route', '(a/)?post');
```

But it's clearly not very clean/readable so probably not recommended.

Comment: Thanks, I use foreach to wrap all rules. It seems no elegance way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

RealRoutes.php:

```
Route::get('post','PostController@index');
// ... include all of your other routes here
```

routes.php:

```
include('RealRoutes.php');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'a/'], function () {
    include('RealRoutes.php');
});
```

There's probably a better way to solve this using a lambda function or similar but the above should work as a quick solution.

Comment: I have some different route group, so use @Ben Swinburne 's answer. Still thanks.